# How do I post some variables to a file using opencart in admin custom page

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller, e-commerce, opencart

I am trying to post some variables to the same custom admin page. And here is my code.

Calling the javascript function from controller custom/custom.php

```
class ControllerCustomCustom extends Controller {

public function receive(){
    $this->session->data['file_name'] = $this->request->post['file_name'];

    }
public function index(){

$this->send_val("Javascript: test('file_name');");

if(isset($this->session->data['file_name'])) { 

    $this->data['file_name'] = $this->session->data['file_name'];
}

}
```

**javascript function**

```
function send_val(file_name){
    $.post('index.php?route=custom/custom/receive', { file_name: file_name});
    }
}
```

**custom.tpl**

```
<?php if(isset($file_name)) { ?>
<div><?php echo $file_name; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am not able to get the Posted values. I have followed one of the stackoverflow's resolution provided in "[How do I post some variables to a file using opencart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899193/how-do-i-post-some-variables-to-a-file-using-opencart?rq=1)". But the same is not working for me. Is there anything I have to add to opencart.

Comment: Hi team, need your assistance in this. Am I doing anything wrong here?  I am new to opencart.

Comment: i don't think you can really call a javascript function from within the controller - javascript is client side so it should be in the view/template

Comment: i tried by placing it in custom.tpl, but no go. Here I can get success message in after posting the values from ajax / javascript, but not able to get the posted values from php side.

Comment: Can any one assist me.. I am still waiting.. Any link for guidance, tutorials, anything which could help me...